# How to add multiple data items to a picker view in Swift for Xcode 11.5

Tags: swift, xcode, drop-down-menu, uipickerview, pickerview

How to add around 3500 items in the picker view or some easy drop down list kind of elements from the data provided in the csv file and also map them with individual values corresponding to that data. Any automation or easy technique to do so in Xcode?
eg for data item in csv format

```
item 1     item 2 (value to be mapped in picker view 
                    along with displaying in the view view)

----------
abc        1
----------
def        2
```

Comment: can you not import the csv into coredata and then hook that in. you can define the id and mapp it next time you update the file. Just a thought. Doing it in a picker view will then be pretty straight forward.,

Comment: thanks definitely gonna try that approach